# Basic German books of novel to learn the language for beginners (1000 words or A1/A2 level)

Tags: book

I'm looking for some easy books to read like the following one which is in English, but I need some in German: [link](https://www.google.at/search?q=the%20picture%20of%20dorian%20gray%201000%20words&oq=the%20picture%20of%20dorian%20gray%201000%20words&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64l2.1200j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

But the search is not very easy since I find a lot of "false positive" like the following one: [link](http://www.amazon.it/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?__mk_it_IT=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=books%20english%201000%20words%20vocabulary)

The problem is that in English I can look for the name of the book or for the author and look for a simplified 1000 words only version. But I can't do the same in German.

The definition of this type of books in english is: "*collection of adapted classic literature and original stories develops reading skills for low-beginning through advanced students.*"

Comment: You might want to take a look at our [list of simple but interesting books](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/620/simple-but-interesting-german-literature)

Comment: Google for Easy Readers, German DAF.

Comment: I've also found to look for "Deutsche Lektüre für das GER-Niveau A2"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Germany, "1000 words" is not a brand of sorts, if you will, for simplified books. That said, there *are* some sites catering to that need:

http://www.einfachebuecher.de/

I'm sure there are others. If you want to use a simple websearch, use the title of the book plus "vereinfacht" (= simplified), that should turn up a few hits. Good luck with your search!

Comment: Thanks, I've followed your advice and I found this website. But it's in german. I'm looking for a book like a novel which can be read by an A1 or A2 level person. Can you look if you think this site is good for me? http://www.lektueren.com/deutsch-als-fremdsprache/titel/niveau/A1.html (I've seen also this other link http://www.hueber.de/deutsch-als-fremdsprache/)

Comment: It *does* say "Empfohlen für Niveau A1, A2" (Recommended for levels ...) so this certainly seems suitable. Another term to keep an eye out for is "Deutsch als Fremdsprache", often abbreviated as "DaF".

Comment: vielen danke!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this ebook [http://www.amazon.com/Aus-Liebe-Pralinen-Beginners-Edition-ebook/dp/B00VIKBYBU](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00VIKBYBU)

It it a perfect novel for German beginners up to level A1, written with very simple sentences, suitable grammar for a beginners and an English dictionary in the end of each chapter.

Comment: Als Erstbeitrag riecht das doch verdammt nach Spam.