# Good children author for learning German

Tags: vocabulary, learning

I would like to read some good German children's stories with simple German where I can improve my German. Can you please tell me whom I should read.

Comment: Depends on your level. Books for Kindergarten children or school kids? Also books about common life situations are always suitable. Too broad for an answer. Probably any author who fits your level.

Comment: Look at the list we have here: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/620/simple-but-interesting-german-literature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember Grimms Märchen from my childhood.

http://www.grimmstories.com/de/grimm_maerchen/index

Comment: I like these stories, too, and I'd even say they are a _must read_ for everyone interested in German culture. But "simple German" for somebody who wants to learn and improve his German? There I have doubts. You will find old-fashioned phrases like "Nun traf es sich, daß er mit dem König zu sprechen kam, und um sich ein Ansehen zu geben, sagte er zu ihm..." all along which might by a challenge for language learners.