# An appropriate sequence of books to learn German

Tags: learning

Now I don't know anything about German but I want to learn German up to level C1. I plan to learn German alone as much as possible. So I'm looking for books to help me reach my goal. I intend to first learn about IPA (International Phonetic Alphabet) and phonetics. I found an excellent material about phonetic in the book "The German Language - A Linguistic Introduction" written by Jean Boase-Beier and Ken Lodge. I also found some sites that complement this material. After I learn about this I plan to read the book "Hammer's German Grammar and Usage". However I don't know what material I should learn after this book.

Researching I have seen that the Cornelsen books are excellent however they are not digitally available (I can't access the books through the Kindle, for example) and they come with CD's. I don't have any CD players.

Could you give me a collection of books (and tell me in which order I should read them) that will allow me to reach the desired level?

I intend to study this way because I believe that this is the most systematic way to learn German. I'm not interested in conversation right now, but at the right time I'll look for a teacher to practice conversation. My initial goal is to be able to read Mathematics, Physics, Biology and Chemistry books in German as fast as possible.

Comment: You may find this Q&A here interesting: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/620/simple-but-interesting-german-literature

Comment: @Takkat I'd like books like those "Studio" from the Cornelsen publishing house. But I won't use them because they come with CD's and aren't digitally available. Do you know of a collection similar to this one that meets these prerequisites? Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Perhaps you want give www.iwdl.de  a try. That's a website by the German Adult Edcuation Association, as a virtual learning enivornment for learning German. It is free. It covers only levels A1, A2 and B1, but for a start it might be useful. Don't shy away from the pretty outdated graphic design...

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Thank you very much! I liked the site. I also found the books I was looking for. On Cornelsen's website I found the "Studio [21]" digitally available.

Comment: Did you see the question about [resources for learning German](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9526/resources-for-learning-german) already?

Comment: Welcome to German Language SE. I am closing your question due to several problems: 1) It is unclear what you are struggling with. On the one hand, you say your focus is on reading scientific texts, on the other hand you focus on the spoken word (IPA, audio material). 2) Even with your restrictions, it is very broad and will attract a lot of answers. 3) It is not clear what you wish beyond the linked answers. 4) It is unclear at what level you are currently at. If you are learning German from scratch, you seem to be planning ahead for far too long.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I said "I don't know anything about German". My goal's to reach level C1 in German. But I chose as an initial goal to learn enough German to read scientific books. I'm learning IPA because the book "Hammer's German Grammar" uses this alphabet to teach how to pronounce words. What I want is to find a sequence of books that'll allow me to learn German in less time. Yesterday I decided to read the book "German Grammar Made Easy" first. Reading this book I'll understand the structure of German which will allow me to already study scientific books in German.

Answer (score 1):

Most recent German language textbooks now come with some means to download audio data. Some offer it without any restrictions on the Internet (I think Hueber does this a lot), some have download address and an access code printed somewhere near the imprint (very very early in the book).

Comment: This certainly isn’t suited for a comment. If anything, it’s an answer.