# Pop quiz activities for German

Tags: english-to-german, standard-german, reference-request

Is there a place like google word couch or *any* quiz place for German? I have recently started learning German from Youtube (Lingoni german) and a mobile app Duolingo. Now, while going through a few answers, I have seen that German StackExchange hates learning languages from youtube. But my country is completely under lockdown, so there are not many choices. Like any beginner, I am facing a huge challenge with German pronunciations *(if anyone has any advice please help me, I am desperate!)*. I was hoping if there were places where I can read stories in German (like children book stories), or like I mentioned above, word couch or quiz places that can help me in my endeavors.

Comment: Maybe you find something in our collection of resources: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9526/resources-for-learning-german
I don't see the problem with using Youtube, there are excellent channels on there.

Comment: You can find many resources for learning German in [this answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/9526/43989); even if it's not exactly what you had in mind there is sure to be something useful for you there. I've never gotten the impression that this site hates learning from YouTube, but I'd definitely say YouTube should not be your _only_ resource. Trying to learn German from children's stories can be problematic and what you should probably be looking for are graded readers. They're not free, but the prices should be reasonable and if you're desperate then it should not be an issue.

Comment: Pronunciation is not the main motive of my question. **What I want is a place like google word couch where I can practice, I have found only one such resource, but the questions are quite advance.** _[Here on the right side](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/german-english/jung)_

Comment: @RDBury with that children story statement, I was actually trying to replicate the way I learnt English in my childhood: words. sentences, and lots of reading.

Comment: Not a full answer, but https://german.net/ has some nice interactive elements like vocabulary quizzes for free.

Comment: You might check [this answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/620/43989) for reading material. If you want to read children's literature then no one is trying to stop you. I've tried that route myself, in fact. But children and adults have different interests, so a children's story is less likely to engage your interest. Also, children's literature may have simpler vocabulary, but it often still has idioms, colloquialisms and regionalisms that can make understanding a challenge for learners. So what worked for you as a child might not be the best choice as an adult.

Comment: @RDBury That answer will be helpful once I cross the A2 level, currently I am at A1 level (Recently started at that), but yes, that answer will help. The concern you raise about reading children's book is also true, now that I think about it. I guess I will wander the internet in search of A1 comprehensions.

Comment: "Galgenmännchen 2" app - it's a hangman game with 3 difficulty levels, "Wortsalat" app, and "Flizz Quiz" app for higher level than A1

Comment: @Andra Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

I am a self learner too.

For **pronunciation**, I use Leo(dictionary), Reverso(translation site) and youglish.

- https://www.leo.org/german-english
- https://www.reverso.net/text_translation.aspx?lang=EN
- https://youglish.com/pronounce/vorhaben/german?

German **reading material** (with audio) that I like...

- https://www.nachrichtenleicht.de/nachrichten.2005.de.html
- https://www.dw.com/de/deutsch-lernen/das-sagt-man-so/s-32376
- If you like Netflix (even youtube), you can use this extension on computer or laptop to help translate the subtitle (not on Android phone though). You can save the words for review later as well.  https://www.languagereactor.com/

**Listening**...

- https://www.lingoneo.org/learn-german#level-a

**Grammar exercises**...

- https://german.tolearnfree.com/free-german-lessons/
- https://www.lehrerlenz.de/
- https://deutsch.lingolia.com/en/grammar
- https://www.goethe-verlag.com/tests/ED/ED.HTM

For grammar, I find having a **text book** to be useful to ensure a more systematic coverage.

- Basic German: A Grammar and Workbook (by Heiner Schenke and Karen Seago, Published by Routledge) - Very basic
- Grammatik Aktiv (published by Cornelsen) - the book is written in German, also includes a code to access online audio listening exercices.

Comment: Hello Hammie, thanks a lot for all the reference material you have provided. This will help me very much for times to come.

Comment: @Momobear :) The little that I can do to give back to such a supportive community! 
Anyway, there is another SE page that has even more resources listed...
https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9526/resources-for-learning-german

Comment: Thanks a lot, Hammie!!

Answer (score 0):

[www.deutsch-ueben.tk](http://www.deutsch-ueben.tk) and [www.deutschlernerblog.de](http://www.deutschlernerblog.de) have lots of free exercises with explanations. The activities have corrections, so you receive feedback (from the computer, of course). The web site of Goethe Institut has free activities and videos too. The three of them sort the activities according to the language level, so you should do those for A1 level.