# Dual language phrases or short stories online?

Tags: translation

I want to find some side-by-side very short stories 1 or 2 pages online in English and German. I have memoried most common words in German but a few uncommon ones per page can disrupt me. "Geier" to "Vulture" was one I had to use translate on.

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. I have never checked all of it, maybe some of these sources do as you like: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9526/resources-for-learning-german

Comment: what did you find by searching for e.g. "short stories side by side german english" in the search engine of your choice? Because that's what I did and is the only base of my answer...

Comment: The disadvantage I see in this style of learning is that you don't immerse in German, but keep switching between languages. The skill that you want to learn isn't the translation between English and German text, but the ability to understand and express yourself in German. Other languages should not interfere with this skill.

Answer (score 1):

A very uncommon approach would be reading the bible:

Side-by-side reading of e.g. Luther17 & King James editions [on bibleserver.com](https://www.bibleserver.com/LUT.KJV/Psalm74%2C21)

Less religious:

- 9 books [linked on learnoutlive.com](https://learnoutlive.com/bilingual-german-english-books/) (e.g. [Alice in Wonderland](http://bilinguis.com/book/alice/de/en/))
- some 15-20 stories [on germanamericanpioneers.org](http://germanamericanpioneers.org/GermanEnglishStoriessidebyside.htm) as PDF (not all working)

Comment: @community: maybe that should be integrated into an answer of here? https://german.stackexchange.com/q/620/36160 Or directly inside the answer https://german.stackexchange.com/a/9536/36160? Opinions?

Comment: Good idea, I'd prefer the second link, which is more often referred to.