# Welche Bücher sind für das B2/C1 Niveau gut geeignet?

Tags: vocabulary, learning, book, literature

Ich suche nach Büchern, mit denen ich meinen Wortschatz verbessern kann. Natürlich wäre es schön, wenn das Buch ein Klassiker, *Pflichtlektüre* oder interessantes Buch auch in der Richtung Wissensaufbau sein. Es sollte für das B2/C1 Niveau geeignet sein. Es macht keinen Spaß, wenn ich bei jeder Seite 20 Wörter nachschauen muss. Gleichzeitig sollte es nicht zu leicht sein.

Comment: Ein guter Startpunkt ist [diese Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/620/simple-but-interesting-german-literature), aber ich fürchte, dass eine Klassifizierung wie B2/C1 praktisch nie auffindbar ist.

Answer (score 1):

Als Studentin für die C1 Zertifikatprüfungen schlage ich vor:

- Station C1 von Praxis, Spiros Koukidis, Jörg Kassner

und auch

- Treffend B2 von Christos Karabatos, Jo Glotz - Kastanis.

Answer (score 0):

Es gibt dieses Leseheft von Hueber-Verlag «Der Ruf der Tagesfische und andere Geschichten». Dort drin sind Kurzgeschichten, Worterklärungen und Übungen zum Leseverstehen.

Das und weitere Hefte gibt es hier (auf Niveaus B2, C1 und C2): https://shop.hueber.de/de/sprache-unterrichten/deutsch-als-fremdsprache-daf-daz/lekture/niveaustufen/b2-c1-c2.html

Viel Spaß beim Lesen!

Comment: This is awfully close to an advertisement. Are you affiliated or is that your material?

Comment: No, I have no affiliation with them and it's someone else's material. These kinds of books can be hard to find, especially at that level, and several years ago I did the tough leg work to find them.